# Group average temperatures by time

Tags: mysql, time, group-by, average

My table with temperature values gets updated every hour.

```
ID      Temp    Hyg     Time
...
3203    13      62.7    2015-05-01 09:16:19
3204    12.93   62.9    2015-05-01 10:16:19
3205    13.12   64.9    2015-05-01 11:16:20
3206    13.5    65.7    2015-05-01 12:16:20
3207    13.75   65.8    2015-05-01 13:16:20
3208    13.93   65.6    2015-05-01 14:16:21
3209    14.06   65.7    2015-05-01 15:16:21
...
```

Till now i displayed the data in a graph, showing the last 50 hours(=records).

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `tblEnvironment` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50) sub ORDER BY id ASC
```

But now I need to display a larger timeframe without exceeding 50 display points.

How can I merge e.g. 3 records to one with the average temperature of the 3?

Answer (score 2):

This solution is for the case, that your ID column may have gaps. Therefore we create a rownumber column, so we can decide upon it, if it's every third row.

```
select
t.*
, @rownumber := @rownumber + 1
, @groupnumber := if(@rownumber % 3 = 0, @groupnumber + 1, @groupnumber) as groupnumber
from
t
, (select @rownumber := -1, @groupnumber := 0) v
order by id desc
limit 150
```

Then we can group by on this subquery:

```
select group_concat(ID), avg(Temp), avg(Hyg), min(Time), max(Time), groupnumber from (

    select
    t.*
    , @rownumber := @rownumber + 1
    , @groupnumber := if(@rownumber % 3 = 0, @groupnumber + 1, @groupnumber) as groupnumber
    from
    t
    , (select @rownumber := -1, @groupnumber := 0) v
    order by id desc
    limit 150

) sq
group by groupnumber
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce53b/6/0)

With the groupnumber increasing just every third row, you will get 50 rows in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use GROUP BY:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html

You can group by both a column directly (e.g. time) but also on a function of that column, e.g. you could group on DATE_FORMAT or TIME() to group on a part of the time, e.g. by hour.

Comment: How does that find the average of 3 results from the table?